# Grant access using hierarchies not working

Tags: sharing, role-hierarchy, owd, userrecordaccess

Facing an absurd issue. 
 USER A is aligned with role A. USER B is aligned with role B.
 Role A is at higher level than Role B.
 OWD settings  for a custom object Test_c is Private.
 Through manual sharing i am sharing the record of Test__c object to USER B. 
'Grant access using hierarchy' checkbox is also checked.
 But then also to USER A, the record shared to USER B(through System Admin) is 
 not visible. 
 What could be the reason?

Comment: Are Role B and Role A in the same hierarchy? You could be of higher level but not be in the "chain of command"

Comment: No they are in different hierarchy.We can treat Role A is VP and Role B as Manger . Did not understand by the meaning of "chain of command". Please Explain

Comment: "Grant Access Using Hierarchies" only works on DIRECT reports. That means that if A is "Vp of Sales" and B is "Director of HR", unless HR reports to Sales then people in Role A will not automatically see records owned by Role B

Comment: @SebastianKessel Ok. Now i understood the issue. Thats for DIRECT reporting. Thanks for awesome answer.

Comment: You're welcome. I put it in as an answer to this question. If you don't mind, mark it approved so others can benefit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Grant Access Using Hierarchies" only works on **DIRECT** reports. That means that if A is "VP of Sales" and B is "Director of HR", unless HR reports to Sales then people in Role A will not automatically see records owned by Role B.